# Me gustaría saber ¿cómo hacer que el valor que yo introduzca para cada nota aparezca a un lado y no abajo

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace _1_2_EntradaSalidaDatos_6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double nota1;
            double nota2;
            double nota3;
            double promedio;
            

            Console.WriteLine("Nota 1");
            nota1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Nota 2");
            nota2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Nota 3");
            nota3 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            
            promedio = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) / (3);

            Console.WriteLine("Promedio:" + " " + promedio);

        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Console.WriteLine --> Hace una salto de línea. Console.Write --> sin salto de línea

Answer (score 1):

El **Console.WriteLine(String);** es para escribir en una línea vacía, si quieres seguir escribiendo en la misma línea que estabas escribiendo puedes usar **Console.Write(String);** y para poner una parte de la String en la línea de abajo con **Console.Write(String);** puedes usar **\n** que te permitirá poner lo que esté detrás en la siguiente línea.
Por ejemplo:

```
Código.-
Console.WriteLine("1-Hola.");
Console.WriteLine("¿Cómo estás?");
Console.Write("2-Hola.");
Console.Write("¿Cómo estás?");
Console.Write("3-Hola\n¿Cómo estás?");
Console.Write("4-Hola\n\n¿Cómo estás?");

Salida.-
1-Hola
¿Cómo estás?
2-Hola.¿Cómo estás?
3-Hola
¿Cómo estás?
4-Hola

¿Cómo estás?
```

Espero que te sirva :)

Answer (score 0):

Buenas otra versión a la de @GzDany sería usar Console.Write + Console.readline()

```
 double nota1;
        double nota2;
        double nota3;
        double promedio;


        Console.Write("Nota 1:");
        nota1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Nota 2:");
        nota2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Nota 3:");
        nota3 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        promedio = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) / (3);

        Console.WriteLine("Promedio:" + " " + promedio);
        Console.ReadLine();//Pausa
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]